# bash + what the opposite operation of the unset command + add arr member

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

Deleting value from array in bash is very simple as the following:

remove the first value from array:

```
   arr=(1 2 3 4 5 6)

   unset arr[0]

   echo ${arr[*]}

   2 3 4 5 6
```

remove the second value from the last array:

```
  unset arr[1]

  echo ${arr[*]}

  3 4 5 6
```

But how to add new value to array in bash ? , is it possible?

for example - add the value 10 after the first arr member

```
 3 10 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
arr=(1 2 3 4 5 6)
unset arr[0]
unset arr[1]
arr[1]="${arr[2]}"
arr[2]=10
echo "${arr[@]}"
3 10 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an item `5` to table `arr`

```
  arr=(${arr[*]} 5)
```

Ordering in bash is made throught sort command...  Otherwise I advise you to use an other language.